# Ember binding between controllers

Tags: ember.js

Upgrading to last version of ember (1.0.0-rc.8) i found a difference on resolution of bindings and they are not working properly.
This is the example:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  exploration: Em.Object.create({
    activeUser: Em.Object.create(),
  }),
});

App.PageController = Ember.Controller.extend(
{
  needs: ['application'],
  explorationBinding: 'controllers.application.exploration',
}
```

if i try to get the property exploration by:

```
result = pageController.get('exploration')
```

the result is `null`. Instead if I try to get

```
result = pageController.get('controllers.application.exploration')
```

the result is the instance of exploration object.

Is a Bug or a normal behavior?

**UPDATE** The problem is resolved upgrading to last release 1.0.0 (*31/08/2013*) and was connected to the [Issue 3265](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/3265)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of small issues about binding order. 
But basically bindings are being semi-deprecated in favour of CPs

So your controller should look like:

```
App.PageController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['application'],
  exploration: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.application.exploration')
})
```

Comment: Yes is correct to use this approach and it works. 
My problem was also connected to a timing issue on call `setupcontroller` on routing system. If this function call the bound property, ember was not able to resolve it. Now is resolved with the 1.0.0 release